# How to set a NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace ? Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, nscolor

I need to set a color.

In my case the color returned by a `NSColorWell` is `NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace 0 1 0 1`. If I set this color the app crashes. How can I manipulate it ?

Thanks

Comment: set a color where? give more details. Post what you have done.

Comment: Well,  i got my color saved on a plist with that format and I am trying to set it back to the colorWell when the app launches